# Opção padrão no select não aparece

Tags: html, css, angular

Tenho um select que quero mostrar uma `label` como opção padrão, mas ela está aparecendo em branco.

Meu select:

```html
<div class="select">
    
    <select (change)="calculaMes(mesEscolhido)" [(ngModel)]="mesEscolhido" name="selectMesEscolhido"
    class="select-text">
       <option class="dropdown-item" disabled selected value>Teste</option>
       <option [hidden]="datasComMovimentacoes[x].data == mesEscolhido" *ngFor="let mes of datasComMovimentacoes;let x = index"
       class="dropdown-item">{{mes.data}}</option>
    </select>

   <span class="select-highlight"></span>
   <span class="select-bar"></span>

</div>
```

Esse é o resultado que eu tenho no meu template:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E cade a tag `<label>`?

Comment: Para adicionar um valor padrão basta adiciona-lo ao model,  `this.mesEscolhido = SUA OPCAO` no arquivo ts, o proprio angular vai achar o valor na lista de options  e selecionar